# Order of multiple IOperationInvoker on the same operation

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any built-in possibility to tell WCF exact order in which I want my custom operation invokers to be executed?

---

Some background: I have several custom operation invokers in WCF and each of them performs one task, like:

- Set active user
- Check for access rights
- Set culture information
- etc.

Order is very important, because I need first determine user and only then check rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any built-in possibility to tell WCF exact order?

No. There’s no WCF interface to for that.

> Can you control the order through configuration?

Yes. The order of execution of the different IOperationInvoker’s is predictable and controllable through configuration. You could use this to meet your requirements.

**IOperationInvoker Background**

Carlos Figueira’s blog: [WCF Extensibility – IOperationInvoker](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20SiteHome%20(Microsoft%20%7C%20Blog%20%7C%20MSDN)) gives an example of a custom invoker. Probably too much information, but it shows how multiple invokers chain together and how they are configured and applied to the operation through a WCF behavior.

My point is: OperationInvoker's are interceptors. Each time a new invoker is added to the operation, the previous one is stored.

In other words from the example the behavior that applies the invoker looks like this:

```
public class CacheableOperationAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    // omitting lots of code...
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new CachingOperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker, this.secondsToCache);
    }
}
```

And the invoker stores the previous invoker:

```
public class CachingOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    // omitting lots of code...
    public CachingOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker originalInvoker, double cacheDuration)
    {
        this.originalInvoker = originalInvoker;
        this.cacheDuration = cacheDuration;
    }
}
```

Then the invoker method looks like this:

```
public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
{
        // do this invokers work before others?...

        // at some point call the next invoker
        object result = this.originalInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);

        // do this invokers work after others?...

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note: You need to know the invoker implementation (when it calls the next invoker in the stack) to fully understand how multiple invokers sequence. There's no rules or conventions on this (for good reason).

**Configuration**

WCF behaviors can be added to an operation in a couple different places: code, config file, etc. So many options can cause confusion (bugs) for your use case.

**If your OperationInvokers are tightly coupled, my suggestion would be to create a single custom behavior that adds all the IOperationInvokers in the right order.**

So while you can't "tell" WCF the execution order, you can predictably control it.